# Order categories by descending order in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a profile for clinics where I can show doctors under each specialization. I want to show the specialization with most doctors to least doctors.

For instance:

```
Dentists:
Names of all dentists (7)

Pediatricians
Names of pediatricians (4)

OB/GYN
Names of all obgyns (2)
```

models.py

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1300)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization, related_name = "doctor_specialization")
    sub_specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization, related_name = "doctor_subSpecialization", null = True, blank = True)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic)

class Clinic(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = True, null = True, unique = True)
        contact_no = models.IntegerField() 

class Specialization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

views.py

```
def clinicProfile(request, slug):
    clinic = get_object_or_404(Clinic, slug=slug)
    doctors = Doctor.objects.all().order_by('-netlikes')

    d.update({'clinic': clinic, 'doctors': doctors, })

    return render(request, 'm1/clinicprofile.html', d)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple.Instead of using `('-netlikes')` just use `('netlikes')` and it should work. Your function should look like this.

```
 def clinicProfile(request, slug):
 clinic = get_object_or_404(Clinic, slug=slug)
 doctors = Doctor.objects.all().order_by('netlikes')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [backward annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards), and it will look like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Min, Sum, Avg
specialization = Specialization.objects.annotate(Count('doctor'))
```

Comment: could you elaborate? Where exactly should i use this? I'm very new to django.

Comment: In clinicProfile
replace this "doctors = Doctor.objects.all().order_by('-netlikes')" 
with the specialization = Specialization.objects.annotate(Count('doctor'))